# JSon Parsing error with double quotes

Tags: android

I'm trying to parse the string "quotes":""living d life till i breathe my last"",
using json parser but its not parsing.I come to know the problem,its due to these double quotes "quotes":""living… in the string.

I have tried these things :

str_response = [str_response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'"  withString:@""];
   str_response = [str_response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""""  withString:@"""]; 
        str_response =[str_response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

But no success,nothing alb to replaces the double quotes with single quote
I want the result:
 "quotes":"living d life till i breathe my last"

Thanks for the help

Comment: are you sure that android tag is a good tag? your code looks like objective C not java ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is in objective C, however, JSON a JSON Object has following formatting:

{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"};

in case of string values.

Please edit your code to following to get string values like that:

```
str_response = [str_response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'\'" withString:@""]; str_response = [str_response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"\"" withString:@""];
```

because, its only way to parse by using json library, but you can define your own parser, for specific problem in json.